# Java: Maximum value in TreeMap

Tags: java, treemaps

If I have a TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

I want to print out the `String` with the highest value. I have seen other questions about sorting, but I am wondering If there is any smooth way to get the maximum value in the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8, a one-liner for getting a key with the highest value is:

```
String s = map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .max(Map.Entry::comparingByValue)
              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
              .orElse(null);
```

`s` will be `null` if the `map` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

No, for that you'd need to switch your key and value. It's the keys that are sorted.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but will a tree reliably sort a primitive wrapper class?

Comment: Yes, they all implement `compareTo()` properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

becomes:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Assuming you want **all** highest value strings, else you only want **any** such string you can use this construct:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
```